# Installing hibernate artifacts from source

Tags: hibernate, gradlew

I want to install Hibernate maven artifacts from source into my local maven repository.

I've cloned the sources from `https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm`.
They are building fine using `./gradlew clean build`.

I've tried:

```
./gradlew clean install
```

but the only artefact installed are:

```
hibernate-gradle-plugin-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
hibernate-maven-plugin-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This is the output of `./gradlew clean install --info |grep Installing`

```
[INFO] Installing /home/rzymek/devel/github/hibernate-orm/tooling/hibernate-gradle-plugin/target/libs/hibernate-gradle-plugin-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  to /home/rzymek/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-gradle-plugin/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/hibernate-gradle-plugin-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/rzymek/devel/github/hibernate-orm/tooling/hibernate-maven-plugin/target/libs/hibernate-maven-plugin-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  to /home/rzymek/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-maven-plugin/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/hibernate-maven-plugin-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Doing `find /home/rzymek/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/ -name *4.3.0*jar` yeld also only these two files.

The question is: How to install `hibernate-core`, `hibernate-entitymanager` artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The answer is:

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```